# Qt Assistant as Custom Help Viewer - Home button doesn't work?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-assistant

The `<homePage>` tag in my .qhcp file doesn't appear to work. Sometimes it seems to set the page I specify in that tag to be the value in `Edit..Preferences..Options..Homepage`; sometimes not. Either way, clicking the `Home` button does not work. Sometimes it does nothing, sometimes it says the page could not be found - and gives what looks to me to be a perfectly valid path.

Any ideas? Or worst case, is there a way to get the viewer to not show the Home button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I clicked Restore to default, and now it seems to work.  Not sure what's going on, but hopefully the problem is behind us...

Answer (score 1):

The `<homePage>` should provide a complete path, i.e.

```
<homePage>qthelp://your.full.namespace/doc/index.html</homePage>
```

Could that be the problem?